# Is it possible to "synchronized if" statement?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a clean way to write out a method that may, or may not be wrapped in a `synchornized` lock based on a boolean. However the only way I can find to do this is very ugly.

```
boolean lock = true;

void remove(Object o) {
   if(lock) {
      synchornized(this) {
          // remove o
      }
   } else {
      // remove o
   }
}
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to do this, perhaps a "Synchronize if" type of statement?

Comment: You can synchronize the method. And no, it's not ugly the way you're doing it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun (public synchronized void remove) will not only be synchronized if "lock" is true, however, which is the point of the question.

Comment: Then your approach is very fine.

Comment: if you feel ugly then have a synchronized method then call it from the if condition

Comment: Who does decide whether to lock or not? In other words: Who is setting/controlling the `lock` variable? And: Are you planning to switch the locking behavior forth and back? Or will it be set once, and then it is _locked_?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You probably have an XY Problem: what problem do you think this will solve?

Comment: If you find it ugly , you can write another remove method which will call the two versions of remove based on flag. public void remove(Object o){if(lock){removeWithSync(o) } else{removeWithoutSync(o)} }  . Then you  can make removeWithSync method as synchronized (and both these should be private)).

Comment: You should probably make `lock` `volatile`, so changes to it are recognized by all threads. Or use an `AtomicBoolean` if you need CAS.

Comment: +1 to duckstep's comment.  The `lock` variable is checked outside of a synchronized block, it ***must*** be declared volatile (or some other form of synchronization used). I also think this is an XY problem: what are you really trying to accomplish here?  There's probably a better way.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can use `AtomicBoolean`:

   ```
   private final AtomicBoolean lock = new AtomicBoolean(false);
   ...

   // compare if it is false and set it to true, no synchronized needed
    if (lock.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        statusMessage = "lock acquired";
    } else {
        statusMessage = "I'm already locked";
   }
   ```
2. or define the method as `synchronized`.

your current check for the lock is not in a synchronized block:

```
if(lock) {
    synchronized(this) {
```

Hence 2 threads may pass this check before you set it to false, the real semaphore there is `synchronized(this)`

Comment: I see that there exist Semaphore Java objects. @Paizo . Are they a good practice or Atomic is better ?